Preventing sunburn from a thick enough ozone layer

How much thicker would a planetary ozone layer (like Earth has) have to be to prevent sunburn from being a huge risk on the surface? Assume the planet orbits a similar star to Earth (G type) and other parameters like Earth (habitable etc).
How I am defining preventing sunburn: a red-haired pale white person could lay exposed in the tropical sun unshaded for many hours consistently and suffer no ill-effects from UV-B exposure (such as sunburn, skin cancer etc).

You don't want them getting a tan either?

....... or vitamin D from the light?

@Kilisi: Type I skin, which I take to be what the question is about, does not tan, except in rare occasional cases.

@AlexP yes, type I skin

@AlexP rubbish, I live in the tropics, everyone tans to different degrees. Except albinos

@Kilisi And redheads, many blondes too, of direct Irish and/or Finno-Scandinavian descent, they may "turn ruddy", i.e. end up with permanently reddened, often freckly, skin, but they're metabolically incapable of building up the skin pigment melanin that is required for an actual tan.

@Ash rubbish, everyone tans to some extent, we get all sorts of people here.

@Kilisi What you are choosing to call a tan for the sake of arguing the toss and the scientific definition of a tan are clearly not the same thing. The majority of people with Type I skin do not have the genes necessary to enable their skin to actually tan. It's a mutation, fixed in some populations, to do with the rate of vitamin D production at high latitudes if I recall correctly.

@Ash I'm not arguing, just telling you chaps you don't know what happens in real life.

@Kilisi There is a definition of what an actual tan is and what it is not you clearly do not understand the difference between your personal preference and a qualitative definition. Additionally I personally know several people with the Type I skin mutation, they do not acquire a tan, freckles yes, burn at the suggestion of sunlight, always, tan no, not after thirty or more years of outdoor work in all sorted of weather, in NZ where the sunlight is harsh. Some of them are my cousins, so glad I missed that particular genetic quirk.

@Ash you still waffling on? The horse died already man. NZ is not harsh. I lived there for over a decade as a forestry worker, it's mild.

@Kilisi As long as you remain under the illusion you have a clue there's something wrong with the world that I feel the need to fix, NZ's UV index is rated as "extreme" by international standards year round. Sometimes you're right but you stick just as hard to your guns when you're wrong and that's a bad plan.

@Ash I'm usually right, you chaps on the other hand.... are mostly full of ..... no offense. You rely on flaky science instead of decades of experience and observation

@Kilisi Science is decades, often centuries, of experience. I should have realised the first time, you only start with the "dead horse" bit when you no longer have a legitimate response to a provable criticism.

Horse is overripe already man, give it up. You chaps and your inane criticisms just detract from the site. The whole skin type/tan thing is irrelevant to the question. Science changes with the wind, has done so for centuries. I've seen many scientific studies that are just rubbish.

Yeah that means "stop talking you've proven your point but I'm too stubborn to admit I'm wrong" noted, ignored. Science changes whenever we have new findings, new experiences of reality, human experience should too but apparently you prefer to stick to what you know even when shown proof that you're wrong.

The so-called ozone layer of Earth is thick enough to block 90% (at the Equator) to 99% (at the poles) of the medium-wave (315–280 nm) UV radiation.
Note that the so-called ozone layer is just a region of the atmosphere where there is more ozone in the air than elsewhere, but the concentration is still very small, around 10 parts per million. Ozone is very unstable. And it is not a "layer"; the concentration of ozone varies smoothly,  with maximum at about 20 km altitude.
Note also that ozone is very toxic and you really don't want to increase its concentration near the surface.
Now, if our current amount of ozone blocks 90% of the UV-B radiation, then doubling it will block 90% of the remaining 10%, so in total 99%. If you triple the amount of ozone then it will also block 90% of the remaining 1%, so in total 99.9%. And so on.
There are two problems with the pale skinned redheads in the tropics:

Their skin does not tan. The skin of most people responds to UV exposure by increasing the production of melanin, which darkens the skin and provides a certain amount of natural protection. But some people of the very pale variety just don't tan, and get sunburned much more easily than the average person.

The ozone layer does exactly nothing to the long-wave (315–400 nm) UV-A radiation, which can also cause skin damage, especially to almost pigmentless pale persons.



Also, by how thick I’m discussing more the average density in the upper atmosphere compared to Earth.

Afaik, UV-A radiation mainly damages the skin through aging, and if I prevent UV-B radiation from reaching the surface, I can at least prevent the need for sunscreen or shade in what would otherwise be very dangerous sun exposure

@casualworldbuilder: OK, I edited the answer to explain how geometric progressions work.

Ok so, theoretically would ozone in the upper atmosphere twice as dense be enough for the effect I’m looking for? Skinburn at the poles is much more unlikely. Not entirely impossible, but unlikely; hence why pale skin is more prevalent there

These days the closer to the south pole you get the worse the Ozone depletion still is and the more radiation gets through, but that's a human caused nuisance not the natural situation.

Sorry but this doesn't actual work, not if you want the redhead you mentioned to be, strictly speaking, human.
Because of how the Ozone in the Ozone layer forms in the first place in order to increase it's concentration in an earthlike atmosphere you would actually have to pump more UV radiation into the upper atmosphere. The percentage of the short and medium wavelength UV that is absorbed by the Ozone layer is going to be constant at a given O2 concentration so you'd burn people even more.
Currently that rate is 90% of short and medium wavelengths, nothing for long-wave (it is simply not absorbed this way), which will still burn you if you have no pigmentation and you're out in it long enough (the phrase "burn by lamp light" is only a very slight exaggeration for some). To absorb 99% of the capturable tropical UV you're looking at upping the global O2 concentration from ~21% to ~42%, that's more oxygen than the prehistoric maximum; when this piece of nightmare fuel was roaming around. This is not quite enough to cause acute oxygen toxicity but it is going to cause massive issues, including but not limited to lowering the autoignition temperature of everything on the planet and causing all land based arachnids and arthropods to grow absolutely enormous.
To actually prevent burning altogether you'd not only need hideous amounts of Ozone but you'd have to add something to the atmosphere that soaks up long-wave UV-A as well. The only material I can think of off the top of my head that interacts directly with UV-A are the Silver Halides and I cannot think of a way to put those into the atmosphere en masse, and long term, that doesn't kill just about everything.

Does the Oxygen concentration have to increase or can I just increase the partial pressure of Oxygen in the atmosphere?

@casualworldbuilder The rate of oxygen interception of incoming UV photons must increase so the concentration must go up to make more of the particles in the way of the UV diatomic Oxygen.

Are there any other ways I could increase the ozone without increasing the Oxygen concentration? Just out of curiosity or speculation.

@casualworldbuilder You would need to introduce a different Ozone creation pathway, Coronal discharge might fit the bill, huge lightening storms in the upper atmosphere.

Interesting. My intent is to create a tropical ‘paradise planet’ that has an atmosphere 5 atm in pressure, mainly of Nitrogen and with a partial pressure of 0.35 atm Oxygen (7% of total concentration). Perhaps the G6 V star it orbits generates an abnormally high amount of coronal discharge in the upper atmosphere, that allows for the generation of a much denser amount of Ozone compared to Earth. This would then make sunburn from UV-B much less likely on the surface. However, doesn’t coronal discharge decrease with lower pressure?

@casualworldbuilder Coronal discharge in terms of Ozone production has nothing to do with the star, it's about electrochemical reactions of atmospheric gases, it has other ramifications on the planetary atmosphere as well, the link is worth a read.

The Wikipedia article you linked doesn’t really say much in terms of what could generate such a high amount of coronal discharge. What could I have in the upper atmosphere that would generate the coronal discharge I need for a much higher concentration of Ozone?

@casualworldbuilder You'd need massive, and continuous, electrical discharge rates (read loads of lightening bolts) at some useful altitude, possibly charge arcing in the ionosphere, or between it and the upper stratosphere would be possible but I'm not the guy to get into the specifics of that, beyond the broad strokes atmosphere and weather, not my thing. You'd run into issues with Nitrogen oxide byproducts as well but those could be, somewhat, useful.

It shouldn't take much. Our ozone layer already blocks 95% of UV-B, and that's with an average thickness of 3mm.
Perhaps add another millimeter for safety and then head down to the beach to sip on some whiskey and contemplate life.

The concentration of ozone in the air varies smoothly, with a maximum of around 10 parts per million at around 20 km altitude. There is no 3 mm band of ozone. Those myhtical 3 millimeters (or actually 300 Dobson Units) are the thickness of a notional layer of pure ozone which would have the same absorptive effect on UV-B as the sum total of all the ozone in the air.

@AlexP good luck with that
